# How to make a 'case'?

Tags: ember.js

I need to display different views regarding a variable.
I have started using a #if or #if else but is it possible to make a case ?

Is the alternative to implement that with multiple #if ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best alternative (and the thing Ember.js encourage) is to define a computed property in your view (or controller), making your switch case in this one, and then direcly use the computed property from the template.

In your case of displaying multiple view, I think you have to implement container view, and play with its currentView property. This should be done directly in javascript. If you give more detail of your use, perhaps I could show you how to start.